# JSON schema validation for array that can have items with different keys

Tags: jsonschema

I am trying to find a schema that will validate a given array having multiple items. The items can have 2 possible values for a key. But all the items should have the same value as the key.

If the 2 possible values are 'primary' and 'secondary', then all the keys should be 'primary' or all the keys should be 'secondary'. oneOf does not seem to be working in this case.

Is there a solution to this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Schema:**

```json
{
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    values: {
      type: "array",
      uniqueItems: true,
      minItems: 1,
      maxItems: 100,
      items: { 
        anyOf: [  
          { $ref: "#/definitions/primaryObj"} ,
          { $ref: "#/definitions/secondaryObj"} 
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  definitions: {
    primaryObj: {
      type: "object",
      required: ["id", "primary"],
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: "string",
          description: "The id",
        },
        primary: {
          type: "string",
          description: "primary value",
        },
      },
    },
    secondaryObj: {
      type: "object",
      required: ["id", "secondary"],
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: "string",
          description: "The id",
        },
        secondary: {
          type: "string",
          description: "secondary value",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  required: ["values"],
}
```

**Sample Input -**

**Input 1 - should PASS validation**

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "primary" : "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "primary" : "world"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Input 2 - should PASS validation**

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "secondary" : "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "secondary" : "world"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Input 3 - should FAIL validation**

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "primary" : "hello"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "secondary" : "world"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear and well written first question! I'll be glad to help you today.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close here. There are two changes you need to make in order to get the validation you want. (I'm going to be assuming you're using draft-07, although this applies to newer drafts also)

First, let's take the top section.

The `anyOf` keyword is specified as follows:

> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if it
> validates successfully against at least one schema defined by this
> keyword's value.
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.7.2

You only want ONE of the referenced subschemas to be true!

`oneOf` is defined similar:

> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if it
> validates successfully against exactly one schema defined by this
> keyword's value.
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.7.3

So we change your schema to check that only ONE of the references is valid...

```json
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/primaryObj"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/secondaryObj"
          }
        ]
      }
```

But this still is incorrect. Let's refresh what `items` does.

> This keyword determines how child instances validate for arrays,
> and    does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.
>
> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.4.1

It LOOKS like we got this right, however the first paragraph in the quote above attempts to convey that `items` applies its subschema value to each item in the array, and not "as a whole array".

What our above subschema is doing, is checking each item in the array by itself, in isolation of the other items, that they are "primary" or "secondary" as you define.

What we WANT to do, is check that ALL items in the array are either "primary" or "secondary". To achive this, we need to move the `oneOf` outside `items`.

```json
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/primaryObj"
          }
        },
        {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/secondaryObj"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Almost there! This almost works, but we still find mixing primary and secondary doesn't cause validation to fail.

Let's check our assumptions. We assume that validation should fail when the instance data has `primary` and `secondary` in objects in the array. We can test this by changing one of the subschemas in our `oneOf` to false, forcing the first subschema definition (primary) to be checked. It should check that all items in the array are primary, and any secondary should cause validation failure.

We have to remember, JSON Schema is constraints based. Anything that isn't constrained, is allowed.

If we look at the definition for `primaryObj`, it requires and defines the validation for `id` and `primary, but this doesn't inherintly prevent additioanl keys in the object. To do that, we need to add` "additionalProperties": false` (to both definitions).

The end result looks like this. You can check out the live demo at https://jsonschema.dev/s/3ZKBp

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "values": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 100,
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/primaryObj"
          }
        },
        {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/secondaryObj"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "primaryObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "primary"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The id"
        },
        "primary": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "primary value"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "secondaryObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "secondary"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The id"
        },
        "secondary": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "secondary value"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "values"
  ]
}
```